# How to skip dialer application and call directly from making a call from app with android cordova(phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Can i make a call from my app directly without having dialer app opened.

I need to call to certain nos from the app but it should not open dialer app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233091/call-predefined-number-automatically-on-android-with-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent out = new Intent();
    out.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("+456")));
    startActivity(out);


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```