# How to jump to the dial page on ios device with Cordova？

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phone-call

I'm using the html tag: `<a href="tel:" data-icon="phonecall">Call My Contact</a>`, but the results is not what I want. I just want to jump to the dial page, could someone help me?

Comment: Your image link is of no use to us; we get a 403 Forbidden message instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of related questions and answers on this site.

Here are just a few:

- [tel link android not working (Galaxy S5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432413/tel-link-android-not-working-galaxy-s5)
- [“tel”, “sms”, and “mailto” no longer working in Android after upgrading to cordova 3.6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271313/tel-sms-and-mailto-no-longer-working-in-android-after-upgrading-to-cordo)
- [Cordova + android : not able to open dial pad or mail intent from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669393/cordova-android-not-able-to-open-dial-pad-or-mail-intent-from-app)