# Start Call on Phonegap App

Tags: cordova

I am using phonegap to build an app. I want a user to press a button and make calls to specefic numbers.

However phonegap's call function opens the dialer with number prepopulated.

I dont want that.

I want the call to be started right away.

Comment: Possible duplicate: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233091/call-predefined-number-automatically-on-android-with-phonegap

Comment: also see this: http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/02/making-a-phone-call-from-within-phonegap-in-android-and-ios/

Comment: Thank god Android/iOS do not allow that for obvious security reasons ;)