# Can I start a call from a hybrid application by clicking on one button using MobileFirst?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, phone-call, hybrid

i want to develop a hybrid application which makes a phone call to a static number automatically when clicking on a button using mobilefirst.can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to IBM MobileFirst. A bit of googling would've given you the answer you needed...

Here are a couple of options to open the dialer with a number:

- Directly in the HTML (you can style the `a` to look like a 'button'): `<a href="tel:+1-800-555-1234">call this number</a>`
- Using JavaScript code to be called in a function: `document.location.href = "tel:+375292771265";`

Edit:

It seems that you want to auto-dial.

- iOS: In iOS this is not allowed in webpages. Worklight apps are essentially web code and thus considered a "webpage" by the OS and will thus first display an alert confirming if the end-user truly wants to call this number or not. In a native app the dialer will auto-dial. This can be read in the iOS documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html
- Android: not allowed by the OS. You may be able to achieve this using a Cordova plug-in: see [how to create Cordova plug-ins in MobileFirst Platform Foundation](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/adding-native-functionality/) and [a possible functionality implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233091/call-predefined-number-automatically-on-android-with-phonegap).

Comment: I tried the code below :it  gives me number to call on the dialer screen but it doesn't make the call automatically

Comment: You did not specify which platform (iOS, Android, ...) are you attempting this on. In iOS for example this is not allowed in webpages. A web app, essentially runs web code and thus is considered a "webpage" by the OS and will thus first display an alert confirming if the end-user truly wants to call this number or not. In a native app the dialer will auto-dial. This can be read in the iOS documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: I tried to run this code on android platform, and it didn't work.                                            Should i develop the functionality in a native way?

Comment: This is not possible for web apps. You may need to implement a Cordova plug-in to accomplish auto dialing for Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233091/call-predefined-number-automatically-on-android-with-phonegap